Display video/audio using XHTML
I have an XHTML document that I am parsing using JTidy, but Inow want to include video content. JTidy strips out the <video> elements, and I am told that this is because <video> is not a valid XHTML element. Can anyone tell me what the proper XHTML-compliant way to display video (or play audio) is?

(1) Parse the XHTML first then later add the <video> tags after the JTidy calling function is finished. (2) Why is it XHTML code instead of HTML5 code, if you need to have HTML5 media tags?
